# How to continue the intern test once timeout for leadfoot/Session#executeAsync calls has reached

Tags: javascript, intern, leadfoot

There are array of URLs to load within an application. A page ready event is fired once the page load. However, when running on sauce labs, the event does not fire on a random page and test fails.

Is there any way to continue the tests if the event does not fire?

```
              return remote.get(url)
                          .setExecuteAsyncTimeout(20000)
                          .then(function() {
                                var pageLoadEvent = conf.get("pageLoadEvent");
                                console.log("waiting for " + pageLoadEvent + " event to occur");
                                remote.executeAsync(function(done) {
                                    window.addEventListener(pageLoadEvent, function() {
                                        done();
                                    }, false);
                                }, []);
                            })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `catch` callback after the `executeAsync` to consume the error, although if the ready event can be skipped, is it actually necessary to the test?

You should also return the result of any Command chains created within a `then` callback to ensure the asynchronous chain continues properly. Otherwise, the outer Command chain will continue without waiting for the `executeAsync` to complete.

```
return remote.executeAsync(function (done) {
    ...
}).catch(function (error) {
    // Do nothing here to consume the error, or rethrow it to have the test fail.
})
```