# How can I capture a timeout in intern js?

Tags: javascript, timeout, intern

I would like to execute certain tasks whenever my test has timeout. I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752452/how-to-continue-the-intern-test-once-timeout-for-leadfoot-sessionexecuteasync-c/31754765#31754765) which is very close to what I'd like but is not very elegant and it'd take too long. As, eventually, I have to track all asynchronous calls in my test code and attach a catch call...Besides this there are different types of timeouts `findTimeout`, `pageTimeout` and `asyncTimeout` which complicates the thing.

**Q:** Is there some mechanism in intern js that allows capturing all timeouts or at least on a per-test basis?

Answer (score 0):

May be use of "setTimeout" is solution. Refer this link : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: this doesn't answer the question